# How to unit test a Windows 10 app in Visual Studio?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

How can I unit test a Windows 10 app in Visual Studio 2015?

I created a Blank App Universal Windows project and added a new Unit Test Project to the solution, but when I try to add a reference to my UWP app in the Test Project, I get an error saying 'Unable to add a reference to project "Project Name"'.

[image]

Comment: I think you should be adding a "Unit Test App (Universal Windows)" project

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Right click on your solution and choose `Add > New Project`. Then select `Unit Test App (Windows Universal)`. Make sure that you don't select `Unit Test Library` or `Unit Test Project`. It must be the Universal one. This should generate a base class for you to work with.

You'll probably then want to add a reference to your main project. To do this, right click on your test project and select `Add > Reference` and then choose your main project. You should now be able to create classes from your main project to test.

Answer (score 5):

I can understand the confusion - the Visual Studio team is not consistent in there otherwise fine project hierarchy decisions.

Normal approach was to place Test projects under `Test`. For reasons unknown, they decided to place the `Unit Test App (Universal Windows)` directly under `Windows -> Universal` and hereby bypassing common sense.

**In summary;** Test projects for `Windows -> Classic Desktop` and `Web` is placed under `Test`. Test projects for `Windows -> Universal` is placed under `Windows -> Universal`.

Answer (score 0):

Try RT-Clicking on a function name & see if there is a "Create Unit Tests" option on the context menu.  For some reason adding a new unit test project is buggy, but the context menu worked for me.