# Cannot add Universal project to Unit test project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

When i right click to add reference to my Domain project from my unit test project, I get the following error:

[image]

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Is your UT project is a `Unit Test Library (Windows Store apps)` as described in the following [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj159318.aspx) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unit test a Windows 10 app in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885117/how-to-unit-test-a-windows-10-app-in-visual-studio)